# JavaScript runtime error: 'Promise' is undefined

Tags: javascript, cordova, promise, win-universal-app

I am developing an Apache Cordova app which targets Android, and Windows (Universal), however on the **Windows** platform, I am receiving the following error when running the application.

> 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'Promise' is undefined

This issue seems to be unique to Windows universal apps, **on Android it runs fine**.

The function in question is below:

```
function requestData(ext, params, method) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

        var url = "https://someurlhere/api/" + ext;

        req.open(method, url, true);

        req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        req.setRequestHeader("Authorization", token);

        req.onreadystatechange = function () {//Call a function when the state changes.
            if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200)
                resolve(JSON.parse(req.responseText));

            console.log(req.status + ' ' + req.statusText);
        }

        req.onerror = function () {
            reject(req.responseText);
        }

        req.send(params);
    });
};
```

The error is on the following line:

```
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
```

I'm guessing, as the issue is only occurring on the **Windows** platform, then I'm missing the `Promise` object. I'm guessing this is a file that I need to include in the project.

Any ideas?

Comment: `I'm guessing this is a file that I need to include in the project.` annnndddd?

Comment: Well, the trouble is I don't have such a file, nor do I know where to get it. Assuming that is what the problem is.

Comment: Well, I guess this is your code and you are using a Promise object. Which promise implementation would that be?

Comment: @lex82 probably this is the default/native implementation of the Promise object, which IEs don't support.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should check browser support of the Promise object.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

No support on IEs.

Apache Cordova has `WinJS` built in. So just use:

`return new WinJS.Promise(...)`

Comment: You can still polyfill it though.

Comment: Thanks, didn't even know this is a standard built in object in other browsers!